# builder pattern with java 8 lambda

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm using Lombok currently, but was wondering if is it possible to do something like the below using Java 8?

```
class FooBuilder {
    Optional<Integer> a;
    Optional<Integer> b; 
}

Class Bar {
    public void doSomething (){
        var result = add(p -> p.a(5)
                        .b(3));
    }

    public int add(Consumer<FooBuilder> func){
        // how to extract values from func?
    }
}
```

I tried using a Consumer, but can't get the values.

Comment: Hi there. What are you trying to achieve calling add? The sum of 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: it's just an example but my goal is to avoid doing `FooBuilder.builder().a(5).b(3).build()` or new FooBuilder(..)

Comment: If you want to use a function -- e.g. a `Consumer` -- that operates on `FooBuilder`s, then you have to have a `FooBuilder` instance for it to operate *on*.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Lombok currently

You don't say what part of Lombok you are using, but from context, I'm guessing you mean its `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations for automatically generating attribute getter and setter methods.

In that case, however, this ...

> [I] was wondering if is it possible to do something like the below using Java 8?

... is a non-sequitur.  It either relies on attribute accessors to have been created (whether via annotation processing or ordinary coding or some other mechanism), or it relies on direct access to the fields.  Either way, it does not itself provide accessors to class `FooBuilder`'s fields.

> I tried using a Consumer, but can't get the values.

A `Consumer` is a function that accepts one argument and returns nothing.  Given some means of write access, a `Consumer` could assign values to an object's fields, which you could then read back from that object.  For example, if your classes `FooBuilder` and `Bar` are in the same package, then the default-access of `FooBuilder`'s fields would allow `Bar` instances to access them directly.  In that case, you might use a lambda this way:

```
class Bar {
    public void doSomething () {
        var result = add(p -> {
            p.a = Optional.of(5);
            p.b = Optional.of(3);
        });
    }

    public int add(Consumer<FooBuilder> setValues) {
        // Create a suitable argument for the function
        FooBuilder operandBuilder = new FooBuilder();

        // Apply the function to it
        setValues.apply(operandBuilder);

        // Read out the values set by the function
        return operandBuilder.a.get() + operandBuilder.b.get();
    }
}
```

I don't see much value in doing this job that way, but perhaps there are scenarios where something similar would make more sense.

And any way around, you have to get the `FooBuilder` instance to operate on from somewhere.  Objects don't materialize out of thin air.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid the boilerplate added by Lombok while using Lambdas I think you should implement your own builder method. Something like this (sorry no compiler here to se if it is 100% correct):

```
class Foo {
    Integer a;
    Integer b;

    //no one else will be able to instantiate a Foo
    private Foo() {}

    //getters and setters

    public static Foo build(Consumer<Foo> fooBuilder) {
        var foo = new Foo();
        fooBuilder.accept(foo);
        
        return foo;
    }
 
}
```

Now you can use something like:

```
Foo myFoo = Foo.build(f -> { 
    f.setA(5); 
    f.setB(3); 
});
```

You can also implement fluent setters (idk if Lombok have this feature) if you want to use the one-liner lambda.

I don't know if it still can be considered the Builder pattern.